# MySQL logic issue: Which is the best way to give permission to users to different rows from different tables?

Tags: mysql

We have a few tables: users, units, classes, schedules and marks (can be more)

- users ( id_user, email, password )
- units ( id_unit, name )
- classes ( id_class, id_unit, name )
- schedule ( id_schedule, id_class, start_dt, end_dt )
- marks ( id_mark, id_user, id_schedule, value )

I want to give permission to one user or another to view / update / delete one row from one table.

I can't use roles, because I don't have a particular rule for this.

My solution for this is: create a table named: permissions ( id, table, id_table, id_user, view, update, delete ) and passing users with rows tables, but when this table will have 70k rows, the next statement will take a while ( I tested with a db seeder ):

```
SELECT *
FROM marks
WHERE id_mark IN (SELECT id_table FROM permissions WHERE table = 'marks' AND id_user = '1')
```

Which is the best way to give permission to users to different rows from different tables?

Comment: So, what is the actual question and what does this have to do with php?'

Comment: Sorry, I added the question now: Which is the best way to do this, for a large database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to create [updatable views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-updatability.html) that reference the `permissions` table with a join and use WITH CHECK OPTION to "to constrain inserts or updates to rows in tables referenced by the view." ([source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html)) The permissions will be granted to the views and not to the tables themselves.

You can check if a view is updatable:

> MySQL sets a flag, called the view updatability flag, at CREATE VIEW
>   time. The flag is set to YES (true) if UPDATE and DELETE (and similar
>   operations) are legal for the view. Otherwise, the flag is set to NO
>   (false). The IS_UPDATABLE column in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS table
>   displays the status of this flag.